What do the three numbers in Perfetto duration mean?
I'm just starting to look into Perfetto via viztracer for Python, and I noticed the "Current Selection" for a slice gives this kind of output:

In particular, it says:

Duration   53ms 926us 800ns

What do the three numbers mean? I've tried searching online, but I've found no explanation ...
The 53 ms does correspond to the width of the slice/event in the visualization, but what are the 926us and 800ns for?

The entire expression 53ms 926us 800ns is the duration: 53 milliseconds, plus 926 microseconds (commonly abbreviated as us or μs), plus 800 nanoseconds - for a total of 53.9268 milliseconds.
Based on the values of the timestamp and duration, it looks like precision is only to hundred-nanosecond intervals here.

The 53 ms does correspond to the width of the slice/event in the visualization

The whole number represents the width of the slice/event but the truncated value of 53 ms is close enough to look like it corresponds.

Many thanks for that, @nanofarad - I myself am used to 53.9268 ms, and this kind of formatting looked so unfamiliar, I honestly thought the 926us or 800ns  referred to "standard deviation" or some other uncertainty - good to know what it actually means!

@sdbbs No problem, my guess/speculation is that it makes it easier to read durations that have a wide dynamic range; going from 53 ms to 20 ns is really easy to miss when skimming quickly, as opposed to 53 ms 127 us 260 ns to 20 ns. Of course, the utility and best format depends on the application; I tend to do high-performance stuff where times often fall into that range of smaller values
